# Activating a Window by Name

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way in AutoHotKey to activate a window by name?  This is the action order I'm hoping for:

1. You press a key combination
2. A text queue appears and you type out a name
3. As soon as a unique closest match is determined, the window is activated

Comment: Can you advise is this for Linux, osx, windows?

Comment: @50-3 - autohotkey works only in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it very simple.

```
^+t::
  InputBox wname
  WinActivate %wname%
  return
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does, and provide a little more information on how this solves the OP's problem. Your code may in fact be correct, but the value of your answer will be much higher if you tell us more about it.

Comment: It's not that hard to guess. I've never seen *any* autohotkey code before but I can guess what it all means.

Comment: @somequixotic: I agree with chipperyman573. It is self explanatory. InputBox is to input the name, WinActivate is to activate that window.